# Index Creation Failing for ShardedDocumentStore and Sharded Linq Queries Not Supported

Tags: ravendb, sharding

I just implemented sharding with RavenDB. When running it for the first time, this code:

```
tempShardedDocumentStore = new ShardedDocumentStore(new ShardStrategy(), shards);
tempShardedDocumentStore.Initialize();

IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(RavenDataAccess).Assembly, tempShardedDocumentStore);
```

... produces this error:

System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'WriteToRaven.Data.
RavenDataAccess' threw an exception. ---> System.NotSupportedException: **Sharded
document store doesn't have a database commands.** you need to explicitly use the
shard instances to get access to the database commands

First, ShardedDocumentStore does indeed have DatabaseCommands:

[image]

Second, if that just won't work, should it be done like this?

```
IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(RavenDataAccess).Assembly, shards[0]);
```

If so, now my linq query won't work:

System.NotSupportedException: **Sharded linq queries aren't supported currently**
   at Raven.Client.Shard.ShardedDocumentSession.QueryT

```
using (IDocumentSession ravenSession = GetRavenSession())
{
    return ravenSession.Query<T>().OrderByDescending(orderByClause).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

How do I get this to work?

Note: GetRavenSession() returns OpenSession() from the sharded document store shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bob Horn,
What build are you using? We recently revamped the sharding support.
We have support for linq in sharding now, as well as creating indexes.

Comment: Ahhhhh... I just realized that I'm using build 888 for the server version, but it looks like I'm using old (701) client assemblies. Let me update the client assemblies and see...